# Calling class methods inside main game loop

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to learn pygame by creating a pong game and defining methods for movement in a 'Paddle' class, how can i call that method in my game loop so the paddles' position is updated when the associtaed keys (s,w,up arrow, down arrow)

```
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, heigth) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = heigth

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, WHITE, (
            self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
        ))

    def move_up(self):
        self.y - 10

    def move_down(self):
        self.y + 10
```

game loop:

```
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    left_paddle = Paddle(10, HEIGHT // 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT // 2, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT)
    right_paddle = Paddle(WIDTH - 10 - PADDLE_WIDTH, HEIGHT // 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT // 2, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT)

    while(run):
        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw(WIN, [left_paddle, right_paddle])

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        #this is part of my attempts to accomplish movement, didnt work
        for key in keys:
            if key == pygame.K_w:
                left_paddle.move_up
            if key == pygame.K_s:
                left_paddle.move_down
            if key == pygame.K_UP:
                right_paddle.move_up
            if key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                right_paddle.move_down
        

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost correct.`left_paddle.move_up` returns the method 'move_up' but it does *not* call it. Just add `()` to call the method instead:

```
        for key in keys:
            if key == pygame.K_w:
                left_paddle.move_up()
            if key == pygame.K_s:
                left_paddle.move_down()
            if key == pygame.K_UP:
                right_paddle.move_up()
            if key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                right_paddle.move_down()
```

Comment: Well calling the function doesn't make the rect change its placement on the window, I'm thinking the issue night be me not updating or drawing correctly but idk how the library and it's functions work exactly

Answer (score 0):

While calling the functions adding the parenthesis was needed, the main issue was that I was trying to check if the keys were pressed inside a for loop iterating over the 'keys' map. I don't exactly why it didn't work at all but the gist is that after getting the list instead of iterating over it I just checked for specific key inside keys and then called the appropriate methods.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            left_paddle.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            left_paddle.move_down()
        if keys[pygame.K_y]:
            right_paddle.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_h]:
            right_paddle.move_down()
```